# Install updated application without uninstalling old application

Tags: installation

is there a way to install an updated version of an application alongside the old version of the application (i.e., without uninstalling the old version)?

Comment: i searched many web site..but i could not found.........can u help

Comment: This question is vague. And why is it tagged with C#?

Comment: sorry..regularly i will ask c# question...so some mistake..do not mistake me

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version # should do it, so long as there's no hard-coded changes to system resources that are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "side-by-side installation."  There are a number of examples of side-by-side installation; Microsoft Office products can be installed side-by-side, as can Windows Dynamic Link Libraries (DLL's).

Some programming languages and operating systems allow you to do "hot patching," where the application's code is updated while it is running.  Functional languages such as Erlang are notable examples of this.